# Sensible way to remove irregular noise from images which does not have proper baseline

Tags: image-processing, fft

I am trying to remove noise from a medical image file. The noise pattern in the image file is irregular. It is also hindering with the data pattern of the original image.The image shown below is in `.jpeg` format and it is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94Aw0ZxV8SFbHQ3WlYtN0hQcTg/view)
in `.tif` format. [image: medical image]

The noise pattern in this image is muddled with the actual data pattern which happens to the white streaks of data points in the above image. My goal is to extract the white streams of data points from the noise pool. One of the way to do so is to convert the image in to the signal domain and then masking out specific noise signal.
The image below shows the fourier transform of the image. The problem is the noise pattern is highly irregular and I am having a hard time using gaussian filter. It is not easy for me to distinguish whether I am masking actual data points or the noise patterns. Does anybody has any sort of pointers on how to use filters when the noise pattern is not defined clearly from the data points.Thanks.

[image]

## Edit:

The white stream/trail of data points in red circles:
[image]

Comment: Could you indicate on the initial image an example what you call "white streams of data points"?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Based on the spiky noise pattern you may want to look into median filtering. Looking at that spectrum I doubt any linear filtering will get you anywhere.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/vDGxc8S.png) is an example of 9x9 median filtering.